# JSTL Taglib -error

Tags: java, apache, jstl

i have the following pice of code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If i want to run the programm i get the following error message:

**HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application**

My JAR Files are in the WEB-INF/lib/ folder

--->javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1-javadoc.jar    (IMP)
--->javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1-javadoc.jar (API)

I use the WEB.xml Version 3.0

So please can someone help me?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have added the javadoc of the JSTL instead of the code. Try downloading this one and add it to your lib directory:

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2
```